# Can I populate a list of my own class directly in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

This is the example:

```
public class FotoLiveLove
{
    public string Tipologia { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }
}

IList<FotoLiveLove> fotoLiveLove = xDoc["statuses"].Select(x => new
{
    Tipologia = "twitter",
    URL = (string)x["URLJSON"]
}).ToList();
```

but it says acnnot convert Anonymous type #1 to FotoLiveLove.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to add your class name after the `new` keyword:

```
IList<FotoLiveLove> fotoLiveLove = xDoc["statuses"].Select(x => new FotoLiveLove()
{
    Tipologia = "twitter",
    URL = (string)x["URLJSON"]
}).ToList();
```

Comment: +1. On a side note, if you use object initializer syntax, you do not need the `()`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the type on the `.Select`. Try something like:

```
IList<FotoLiveLove> fotoLiveLove = xDoc["statuses"].Select(x => new FotoLiveLove() 
{
    Tipologia = "twitter",
    URL = (string)x["URLJSON"]
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using the query form in these cases (but that's just a preference):

```
IList<FotoLiveLove> fotoLiveLove = (from f in x.Doc["statuses"]
                               select new FotoLiveLove(){
                                   Tipologia = "twitter",
                                   URL = (string)x["URLJSON"]
                               }).ToList();
```